# Viewing local style sheets/javascript/html using Emulator

Tags: html

I want to view style sheets/html pages via the Android emulator. I pulled the html pages into the SD Card and was able to view them. However, I'm not sure how to pull the style sheets/javascript in to see specific styling.

How can that be done? I'm not a programmer, but can find my way around Eclipse pretty well if that is needed.

Comment: Welcome to Android.stackexchange. Programming questions are considered off topic here and really belong over at stackoverflow.

Comment: Don't know whether to really call this a programming question -- it's not about programming, exactly, but how to "offline view HTML with external stylesheets". This also can apply to several end-user situations I can think of.

Comment: @user28314 I just re-phrased yout question to avoid it being closed as off-topic (see the comments above and on [GreenGuy's answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/39507/16575) below). As pointed out: Development questions are off topic here according to our [FAQ] (please read!), but the real issue you are having IMHO is not. The question itself stayed the same: Please [compare it](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/39480/revisions) to see how to avoid such trouble in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Eclipse. But for your goal, it all depends on how the external stylesheets are defined. If they are using full-qualified URLs (e.g. http://www.example.com/example.css), there's no way you get them working offline. If they are using a relative path (easiest: just their file name, residing in the same directory as the HTML file), you can simply copy them next/relative to your HTML files, and it should work.

Examples, assuming the HTML file is put to `/sdcard/html/myfile.html`:

- `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">`: simply copy `style.css` to `/sdcard/html`
- `href="../style.css">`: Copy to `/sdcard`
- `href="foo/bar/style.css"`: create `/sdcard/html/foo/bar` and place `style.css` there
- `href="/style.css"`: Sorry, nogo without root, as you cannot write to `/`

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the HTML file on your browser, so that you can see the actual styling.

You can also [open a browser via Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528454/how-do-you-open-the-eclipse-web-browser).

PS This really sounds like a dev-related issue. Probably off-topic.

Comment: See my comment above (on the question). Though the *context* here looks like a dev thing, the real *qeustion itself* is not -- I can think of many situations where this might be of interest for "normal users" as well (leaving Eclipse out, as I did in my answer). General rule: If you can re-phrase it (without changing the "real question) so it becomes on-topic, it's not off-topic :) Though the OP probably should do that...